# How to make an element specific when using providers in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic2

After implementing the [following pattern](https://www.joshmorony.com/an-in-depth-explanation-of-providers-in-ionic-2/), I want, however, for only specific pages to have a unique toolbar or header.
Any idea on how that can be made ? Do I need not to inject the provider and have that page as a standalone ?

I am new to Ionic so please let me know if this situation is not clear enough
My current code is the following

```
<ion-content class="no-scroll">
        <ion-header *ngIf="page.pageName != 'MyPageWithUniqueToolbar'">
            <ion-toolbar color="primary" class="sub-header">
                <ion-title class="sub-header-titl1">{{ page.ToolbarTitle }}</ion-title>
            </ion-toolbar>
        </ion-header>
        <ion-content class="no-scroll">
            <ion-nav class="content-body" [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-content>
```

I tried to put the ngIf above like this but it errors out

```
<ion-content *ngIf="page.pageName != 'MyPageWithUniqueToolbar'" class="no-scroll">
```

Comment: so you want to check on the *ngIf whether you are on a page that should show a specific header/toolbar, correct?

Comment: Correct, if I am currently on that page, I dont want to provide any specific header/toolbar and instead have one specified by the actual page.

Comment: First, do not put `ion-header` and `ion-content` inside `ion-content`. Seconde, try to reproduce your problem in https://stackblitz.com/ and share we the link because your error does not relate to `ngIf`

Answer (score 0):

For that `*ngIf` to work you must have a variable `page` defined on all your page components that have this `*ngIf`. If you only define this on the page that you want to show a different header it will error on all the others that don't have a variable `page` defined.

A quick fix for this would be to first check if the variable page exists, and then check the value of page.pageName, like below:

```
<ion-header *ngIf="page && page.pageName != 'MyPageWithUniqueToolbar'">
    <ion-toolbar color="primary" class="sub-header">
        <ion-title class="sub-header-titl1">{{ page.ToolbarTitle }}</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content class="no-scroll">
    <ion-nav class="content-body" [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
</ion-content>
```

Remember, you need the page variable defined in the component, e.g.

```
page = {pageName:'MyPageWithUniqueToolbar'};
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I do have the page variable defined in the component.
When try your ion-content code, I get this error though TypeError: Cannot read property 'isListening' of undefined
    at Menu._updateState (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:86197:26)
    at Menu.paneChanged (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:86232:14)

Comment: Do you have the page variable defined in all the components for the pages that have the *ngIf checking the page.pageName content? About the error, there was a mistake in my answer, which I have now edited and fixed, please try again and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

After some more investigation, I found the solution. By replacing ngIf by [hidden], that did the trick, see below :

```
<ion-nav [hidden]="page.pageName === 'MyPageWithUniqueToolbar'" class="content-body" name="bodyHeader" [root]="state.bodyHeader.current" #bodyHeader swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```